# Replace NaN's in table with 0

Tags: matlab, nan

I have a `table` in `matlab R2015b` with the following data

> var 1             var 2            var 3       
>   Row1         1                     NaN                  2
>   Row2             2                         4                   NaN

I'd like to replace all NaN's in my table with 0's - so something along these lines:

Assume my table is called A

```
newTableA = rowfun(@(x) x(isnan(x)) = 0,A,'ExtractCellData',true);
```

I suppose I could convert my table to a new matrix B, perform, B(isnan(B)) = 0, and convert back to a table, but I thought there might be a more efficient way.

Comment: `A(isnan(A)) = 0`. Works for any dimension

Comment: @JensMunk `isnan` does not work on tables explicitly.

Comment: @excaza By table, I assumed that the author is referring to an ND matrix. Here is works perfectly

Comment: @JensMunk [`table`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html) is a MATLAB class. Hence why he says "I have a table"

Comment: @JensMunk the data is stored in a table, which cannot be passed to isnan. A(isnan(A)) = 0 only works if the data is in a matrix.

Comment: @excaza. Okay, I see, then the rowfun is probably a good solution. Assume it works similar to arrayfun

Comment: @JensMunk yes, that does seem like it's the case, must be why he tried it

Comment: @excaza I have 2013a. Here there is no such thing as a `table` class nor `rowfun`

Comment: @JensMunk rowfun I think would be the way to do it (it works similar to arrayfun), but I do not think you can set an equality in an anonymous function like that.

Comment: @JensMunk as the linked documentation states, it was introduced in R2013b

Comment: @excaza i think the table class began in 2013b. I am using 2015b. I will update the post to clarify this.

Comment: @MarkK I have used similar equality statements using `arrayfun` so I assume the solution that you have is working. I can only anticipate operate with the new `table` class is slow, since I assume this can contain many types and no clever alignment can be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just loop over the variables:

```
t = array2table([1 nan 2; 2 4 nan])
for i=1:size(t,2)
    x = t{:,i};
    x(isnan(x)) = 0;
    t{:,i} = x;
end
```

If you checkout the source code of methods like:

```
>> which table\ismissing
>> which table\standardizeMissing
```

you'll see that is more or less what they do anyway...

Comment: Hm. I like to avoid looping over variables since my tables can get pretty large. I'll try and benchmark this method vs converting between tables and arrays, I think this might end up being a bit quicker in the end. Thanks.

Comment: tables are internally stored using a cell-array of columns (you can peek at the definition `edit table.m` and see for yourself). So this is as fast as it gets.