# writetable replace NaN with blanks in Matlab

Tags: excel, matlab, matlab-table

Given a Matlab table that contains many `NaN`, how can I write this table as an excel or csv files where the NaN are replaced by blanks?

I use the following function:

```
T = table(NaN(5,2),'VariableNames',{'A','C'})

writetable(T, filename)
```

**I do not want to replace it with zeros**. I want that the output file:

1. has blanks for NaN and
2. that the variable names are included in the output.

Comment: If you have NaNs in excel the file gets bigger? weird.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace NaN's in table with 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36315985/replace-nans-in-table-with-0)

Comment: Look here. It looks like you can convert it to a matrix, or do a loop.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36315985/replace-nans-in-table-with-0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need [`xlswrite`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlswrite.html) for that. It replaces `NaN`s with blanks itself. Use [`table2cell`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table2cell.html) or the combination of [`table2array`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table2array.html) and [`num2cell`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2cell.html) to convert your table to a cell array first. Use the `VariableNames` property of the table to retrieve the variable names and pad them with the cell array.

```
data= [T.Properties.VariableNames; table2cell(T)];
%or data= [T.Properties.VariableNames; num2cell(table2array(T))];
xlswrite('output',data);
```

---

Sample run for:

```
T = table([1;2;3],[NaN; 410; 6],[31; NaN; 27],'VariableNames',{'One' 'Two' 'Three'})

T =

  3×3 table

    One    Two    Three
    ___    ___    _____

    1      NaN     31  
    2      410    NaN  
    3        6     27
```

yields:

[image: output]

---

Although the above solution is simpler in my opinion but if you really want to use [`writetable`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/writetable.html) then:

```
tmp = table2cell(T);             %Converting the table to a cell array
tmp(isnan(T.Variables)) = {[]};  %Replacing the NaN entries with []
T = array2table(tmp,'VariableNames',T.Properties.VariableNames); %Converting back to table
writetable(T,'output.csv');      %Writing to a csv file
```

Answer (score 4):

I honestly think the most straight-forward way to output the data in the format you describe is to use [`xlswrite`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlswrite.html) as [Sardar did in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45764228/52738). However, if you *really* want to use [`writetable`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/writetable.html), the only option I can think of is to encapsulate every value in the table in a [cell array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html) and replace the `nan` entries with empty cells. Starting with this sample table `T` with random data and `nan` values:

```
T = table(rand(5,1), [nan; rand(3,1); nan], 'VariableNames', {'A', 'C'});

T = 
            A                    C        
    _________________    _________________

    0.337719409821377                  NaN
    0.900053846417662    0.389738836961253
    0.369246781120215    0.241691285913833
    0.111202755293787    0.403912145588115
    0.780252068321138                  NaN
```

Here's a general way to do the conversion:

```
for name = T.Properties.VariableNames  % Loop over variable names
  temp = num2cell(T.(name{1}));        % Convert numeric array to cell array
  temp(cellfun(@isnan, temp)) = {[]};  % Set cells with NaN to empty
  T.(name{1}) = temp;                  % Place back into table
end
```

And here's what the table `T` ends up looking like:

```
T = 
             A                      C         
    ___________________    ___________________

    [0.337719409821377]    []                 
    [0.900053846417662]    [0.389738836961253]
    [0.369246781120215]    [0.241691285913833]
    [0.111202755293787]    [0.403912145588115]
    [0.780252068321138]    []
```

And now you can output it to a file with `writetable`:

```
writetable(T, 'sample.csv');
```

[image]

Comment: I actually thought of a similar approach until I realised that `xlswrite` does that itself. Do you mind if I include that in my answer? Although I avoided the use of loop and `cellfun` but not sure if it would be any better/faster

Comment: @SardarUsama: If you have another variant for a solution, I'd go ahead and add it. I don't mind. :)