# Replace nan with empty in Table with Multiple Data Types

Tags: matlab

I 'm running MATLAB R2016a. I 'm working on a table like this. It contains multiple data types. Fillmissing function runs in R2016b Edition. What I want to achieve is to replace NaN's with blanks only in numerical data types. The goal is to Export a csv without NaN's in numerical columns. Any idea?

```
    Var1           Var2             Var3
_____________    _________    _____________________

'2101PV'         'QZ'         6,13               
'2102PV'         'QZ'         6,13               
'2103PV'         'QZ'         NaN                  
'2104PV'         'QZ'         NaN
```

Comment: Does `Var3` contain a cell array of vectors?

Comment: No. class(mytable.Var3) = double

Comment: I edited my post.

Comment: So how do you have `6,13` there? Is that just displaying `6.13` with a comma? Also, what alternative value should be used instead of `NaN`, since `NaN` is actually what is typically used for missing numeric values? Are you wanting to remove those rows altogether?

Comment: 6,13 is a number. No, I dont want to drop rows with NaN's. I want to replace NaN's with blank cells

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tab(ismissing(tab)) = {''};
```

But it's not clear how you managed to mix datatypes in your rows...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, as I mentioned I dont want to drop rows whit nan values. Keep them and replace NaN's with blanks

Comment: Edited... this should do the job... but I still can't understand how you managed to mix value types... unless you are using cell arrays with underlying data.

Comment: The reason for this is that I m working on csv files with mix datatypes and somehow some of the blank cells are filled with NaN's. Also, I dont think that isnan can work on a table. It should be converted to an Array, but this works only for the numerical data.

Comment: Under Matlab 2016 you can use a more generic ismissing. I edited my answer. rmmissing is another option but not if you want to keep all rows.

Comment: This could work, but only for the char variables. For numerical no. Anyway, thanks for your answers.

Comment: No, ismissing is universal. From official docs: "ismissing(A) returns a logical array that indicates which elements of an array or table contain missing values, standard missing values depend on the data type:
NaN for double, single, duration, and calendarDuration
NaT for datetime
<missing> for string
<undefined> for categorical
' ' for char
{''} for cell of character vectors"

Comment: indeed, ismissing is universal. However, your assignment includes a char value. And for Var3, the assignment gives an error.

Comment: That's why I was wondering about mixed datatypes (what the heck is a NaN doing among char arrays?)... they are gonna produce a real mess. You should sanitize your data before aggregating vars or manipulating them to their final state. detectImportOptions for CSV files could be your best ally. This will probably point you to the right direction: https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/clean-messy-and-missing-data-in-tables.html

Comment: Ok and mh... and your plan is to convert NaNs in Var3 to empty chars? I don't get the point...

Comment: Yes. The final csv must not include NaN's in the numerical columns.

Comment: You can't... you can't mix types. This is what I'm telling you since the beginning. Either you convert Var3 to string, so you can also allocate empty chars for NaNs, or you keep NaNs. There is no midpoint.

Comment: Ok, if you had only numerical data, what would you suggest?

Comment: Have a loot at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45753690/writetable-replace-nan-with-blanks-in-matlab?rq=1